# VBA: Cannot assign a function's returned value to a variable

Tags: vba, function, module

I have the following VBA code in one of my sheets (i.e. not in a module):

```
Option Explicit

Public timing As String

Sub ButtonLoan1_Click()

    timing = check_timing()
    Application.Run ("loan_" & timing & "_req01")

End Sub
```

The function `check_timing` is defined in a module and works correctly:

```
Function check_timing()
    
    If ActiveSheet.Range("B5") = "Q1 and Q3" Then
        timing = "q1q3"
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("B5") = "Q2 and Q4" Then
        timing = "q2q4"
    End If
    
    Exit Function

End Function
```

However, running the `ButtonLoan1_Click()` Sub returns an error because the variable `timing` is empty, i.e. it is not getting its value from the function `check_timing`, as I would like it to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Within a function, you assign the value to the function name in order to return the value so `check_timing = "q1q3"` and `check_timing = "q2q4"`

Comment: You need to make `timing` public outside of procedures or change your return to `check_timing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you should probably use `check_timing` instead of `timing` so VBA knows this is what the function is returning to whomever called it before.

```
Function check_timing()
    
    If ActiveSheet.Range("B5") = "Q1 and Q3" Then
        check_timing = "q1q3"
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("B5") = "Q2 and Q4" Then
        check_timing = "q2q4"
    End If
    
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: And the `Exit Function` is redundant and can be dropped. Also `check_timing` should probably accept a `Range` parameter instead of using `ActiveSheet.Range("B5")`.

Comment: Also, add the return type of string too